# I executed the mybatis update method of the dao layer, but the database is not updated

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

When I run the junit4 test, I found that the method of mybatis was updated successfully, but the database did not have the updated record, but there is a while loop execution logic below the execution method, is this because of the method has not been executed yet? But when I deleted the while loop and it was updated in mysql.

```
public void executeMethod(Long id) {
    UserMapper.updateById(id);
    while(conditions) {
        // some business
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason of this is that transaction is not committed at the point where you are checking the database.

For example if the `executeMethod` is annotated with `@Transactional` then transaction is stared before the method is entered and is committed after `executeMethod` finishes.  So if you are checking the database before the flow of control leaves `executeMethod` the changes are not committed yet so they are not visible when you query the database from another transaction.